# Node container fails to run using docker for windows

Tags: node.js, docker

I am unable to get my container to run after switching from using docker toolbox to docker for windows. After starting the container it just immediately fails with state `EXIT 254`. This setup was working previously using virtualbox and I am quite stumped at what the problem could be. The build completes successfully.

This is the error:

```
frontend_1     | npm info it worked if it ends with ok
frontend_1     | npm info using npm@3.8.6
frontend_1     | npm info using node@v5.12.0
frontend_1     | npm ERR! Linux 4.4.15-moby
frontend_1     | npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev:no-debug"
frontend_1     | npm ERR! node v5.12.0
frontend_1     | npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
frontend_1     | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
frontend_1     | npm ERR! code ENOENT
frontend_1     | npm ERR! errno -2
frontend_1     | npm ERR! syscall open
frontend_1     |
frontend_1     | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
frontend_1     | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'
frontend_1     | npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
frontend_1     | npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
frontend_1     | npm ERR! enoent
frontend_1     |
frontend_1     | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
frontend_1     | npm ERR!     /usr/src/app/npm-debug.log
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:5

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev:no-debug" ]
```

This is the relevant compose file settings:

```
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    expose:
      - "7777"
    environment:
      - "PORT=7777"
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=7777"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOST=test.example.com"
```

Edit: Add directory structure:

```
C  
└---Users
    |----deepc
         |----docker
              |----myproject
                   |---nginx
                   |---dockergen
                   |---frontend
                        ---package.json, node_modules, src, Dockerfile
                   ---docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: what is the output of `docker run -ti yourimage ls /usr/src/app`?

Comment: Hi i am seeing the correct directory structure which is the same as that on the host: Dockerfile  blueprints  config  jsconfig.json  package.json  tests  README.md   build       coverage    node_modules   server bin circle.yml  interfaces  nodemon.json   src

Comment: Furthermore if i run docker run -ti 50be35c14916 npm run dev:no-debug the application starts up and i dont see the error above.

Comment: So I was right with my answer, `- ./frontend:/usr/src/app` means that if you `docker run -v ./frontend:/usr/src/app -ti yourimage ls` you will have an empty folder

Comment: hmmm when i run the above i get the correct output with all my files there. i.E PS C:\asaf\desfsaeasfasfpc> docker run -v ./frontend:/usr/src/app -ti 50be35c14916 ls -> shows
Dockerfile  bin         build       config    interfaces     node_modules  package.json  src
README.md   blueprints  circle.yml  coverage  jsconfig.json  nodemon.json  server        tests

Comment: Running docker run -v ./frontend:/usr/src/app -ti 50be35c14916 npm run dev:no-debug works as well

Answer (score 1):

In you compose.yml you mount this volume:

```
- ./frontend:/usr/src/app
```

So basically what you did earlier in your dockerfile is useless.

If you don't have a package.json in your `frontend` folder, that's the problem

Comment: Hi I am a little confused by your suggestion, basically my folder structure is app(dir) -> docker-compose.yml, frontend(dir), etc. The frontend directory has my node application inside it with node_modules, package json etc. From reading the docs i was under the impression that the volume is taken relative to that of the docker-compose.yml file which in my case lives 1 directory higher than frontend which is why i reference it as ./frontend. Also I am seeing the correct files inside the container

Answer (score 0):

I think this is hard to debug on a distance like this, but could you try building the container like this and see if it works?

```
FROM node:5

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev:no-debug"]
```

I believe the issue is with:

> no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'

...which tells me that the directory you expect to exist, doesn't! Not completely sure if you need to create the directory before copy, but it would help if you could give us the output of the build log.

Comment: also try with out mounting any volumes and see if that helps

Comment: Hi, oddly the package.json file is inside the container. Ive added a couple comments above.

Comment: Yes the package.json is inside the /usr/src/app but you OVERRIDE this folder with the `- ./frontend:/usr/src/app` in your docker compose so in fine the package.json is not here

Comment: Yes this is most likely an issue with the run command you using where you mount the `/usr/src/app` to an existing directory on your host. as @michael_bitard already has answered. +1 from me